# How to align textlink right end of the table with td element

Tags: html, css, styles, text-align

```
<table>   
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right">
<div style="float:right;">
  <span class="style5 style6">
  <span class="style8">
  <a href="">Forget Password?</a>
  </span>
 </span>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

how to align the link forgetpassword at right corner top of the page

Comment: This alone `<div style="float: right;"><a href="#">Forget Password?</a></div>` simply works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table width is not wide enough to set the link on the right side. Set the table width to 100% and your code will work.

```
<table width="100%">   
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">
<div style="float:right;">
  <span class="style5 style6">
  <span class="style8">
  <a href="">Forget Password?</a>
  </span>
 </span>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```